# What is wrong in "a2 = a1-a1.mean();" to get centered data?

Tags: matrix, variance, eigen3

I am using **Eigen 3.2.4** to obtain a **centred data** in a column vector.

```
Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 1> a1, a2;
a1 << 1, 2, 3, 4;
a2 = a1 - a1.mean(); // error no match for operator -
```

But **gcc** is giving error as **no match for operator -**...
What is the error here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering purely from the documentation, so I may be wrong but.

Eigen does not allow `Matrix - scalar`, but does allow `Array - scalar`

Try either.

```
a2 = a1.array() - a1.mean();
```

Or

```
a2.array() = a1.array() - a1.mean();
```

Even if neither of those work, hopefully they point you in the correct direction.